# Copy Excel range as picture to Outlook mail under text in body

Tags: excel, image, vba, outlook, range

I would like to copy a range from protected Excel sheet and paste it into Outlook as a picture.

My code is pasting the text then the picture, but at the same time deleting the text.

How can I paste the picture under the text.

```
Sub Send_Email()
   
   Dim r As Range
   Set r = Range("NR7:OD39")
   
   Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
   Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   
   Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
   Set OutMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
   Dim StrFileName As String
    
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
   Sheets("table1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="blabla"

   ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8, ColumnLevels:=8

   r.Select
   r.Copy
    
   OutMail.Display
   
   Dim Email As Word.Document
   Set Email = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
    
   With OutMail

      .To = "Name.surname@amazon.com"
      .CC = "Surname.Name@amazon.com"
      .Subject = "Subject"
      .Body = "Hi everybody," & vbNewLine & "actual Status"
      .Display
      
   End With
      
   Email.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
   
   ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1, ColumnLevels:=1
   ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="blabla"

End Sub
```

Comment: Not an Outlook user and not at my computer but `Email.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture` makes the picture the body. So you probably need to add the words and picture to Email then set Email as the body. Can't be more precise right now but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with this line

```
Set Email = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
```

this should do it:

```
Dim ran as Word.Range
    Set Email = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

       With OutMail

          .To = "Name.surname@amazon.com"
          .cc = "Surname.Name@amazon.com"
          .Subject = "Subject"
          .Body = "Hi everybody," & vbNewLine & "actual Status"
          .Display

       End With
    Email.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf
    Set ran = Email.Range(Email.Content.End - 1, Email.Content.End - 1)
    ran.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
```

Comment: it is giving me error in this line:

`Set r = Email.Range(Email.Content.End - 1, Email.Content.End - 1)`

Comment: Oops, sorry. you already defined a `r`, and it is defined as an `Excel.Range`. See changed code.

Comment: Thanks LocEngineer, it works fine. Although, the picture is separating the text. How can I paste it just after the text, as you see I have two lines of text.

Comment: Interesting. It seems the anchor is put at the beginning of the line if the line is not ended with a line break, as in this case. Needs only slight amendment though, see edited code above. P.S: if the spacing between text and picture appears too large for your taste, then use `.InsertAfter vbLf` instead.